# Dynamic test data for test.each Jest

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

Is it possible to assign values at runtime for below Jest test.each example:

```
describe('jb-tests', () => { 
    jest.setTimeout(700000);
    let table: Array<number[][]> = [[]];
    beforeAll(() => {        

        //Below lines are just hardcoded values
        table = [];
        let test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
        table.push(test);

    });

    test.each(table)('.add(%i, %i)', (a, b, expected) => {        
        console.log("inside");
    }); 
});
```

This test case is stuck and not showing any output. If I remove the jest.setTimeout then it fails with message "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test."

Comment: No. `test.each(table)` is evaluated at the same time `beforeAll` is, which is _before_ the callback to the latter is executed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any alternate solution? I have a text file and entries will look like this:
Start case 1
Task1
Task2
End case1
Start case 2
Task 1
End case2...etc.

I will read the file and create test case array based on start and end tags/line and run test on this dynamic data.

Comment: Read the file synchronously, at test discovery time?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comment from @jonrsharpe, you can however specify values in the test.each() call.

```
describe('jb-tests', () => { 
    jest.setTimeout(700000);

    test.each([
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
    ])('.add(%i, %i)', (a, b, expected) => {        
        expect(a + b).toBe(Expected);
    }); 
});
```

However, if you really need data from an external source, and want to process it, you can load it in the test code, or a beforeAll().  Note that the beforeAll() is evaluated at the very start, so what is loaded there is done at the start of processing the file, not as each test is run.

```
import * as NodeJSFS from 'fs/promises';

describe('jb-tests', () => { 
    jest.setTimeout(700000);

    let table: Array<number[][]> = [[]];
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const FileContent$: Buffer = await NodeJSFSPromises.readFile('testdata.txt');

        // Loop through FileContent$ (map, etc.) and load your table (table.push)
        ...
    });

    describe('adding addition describe for this section', () => {
        for (const data of table) {
            ... // Parse data (one element of table)
            it(`should add ${a} + ${b} to be ${Expected}', () => {
                expect(a + b).toBe(Expected);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Steven but my test data is not fixed. It will be dynamic and saved in text file.

Comment: One issue there is then deciding on what you want to test.  Unit tests should be repeatable, therefore, not really dynamic data, as you would then need to write as much code in the tests to validate things works as you would in the main code, leading to another area you might introduce bugs.  Dynamic data might be more of an integration test, and should be handled in that level as well.  However, ultimately you still are writing Javascript.  Therefore you can read a file, parse the data, and then do your testing.

Answer (score -1):

Just found an alternate solution: Populate the test data dynamically and then use describe block to execute test cases using test.each.

```
let test_data: Array<number[]> = [];

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    test_data.push([i+0,i+1,i+2]);    
}

describe('jb-tests', () => { 
    test.each(test_data)('.add(%i, %i, %i)', (a, b, c) => {        
        expect(a + b + c).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    }); 
});
```